# Git fetch adds random text to my code

Tags: git, github, fetch, pull

Im a beginner at using git. I am working on a project using two a work computer and a home pc, saving my code to github as I go. However when I make changes on one computer and want to update the project on the other pc by fetching from github, it tends to screw everything up.

Here is what happens. I used 'git fetch origin' from my work pc to try to update my local repository. But when I load the project, my code has all these extra lines of text that look like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

// code

>>>>>>> 55ef9f7e76d0f27b0fc7f5ca533ccccd07550e8f
```

So obviously it doesnt compile and I have to manually go through and delete all the extra lines. The only way I have found to easily update the code is to just create a new project each time, which is tedious. So, what am I doing wrong? Why does fetch add all this extra lines to my code

Comment: This is standard behavior. Git denotes merge conflicts this way.

Comment: It was a conflict that you didn't resolve, but added as is

Comment: You can read about it here http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts

Comment: Ok, but what if I dont want to merge/merging breaks the code I have? I basically want to delete everything in local and copy it from github. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is git merge conflict. The remote and local versions of the source files, both have changed the same file. Git marks the change from your local head first

```
<<<<<< HEAD
your changes
=======
remote changes
>>>>
```

You have to edit this file manually and resolve the conflict.
[See](http://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts) this how to.

Comment: This answered my question, but i'd rather not have to do this each time I want to update my project. Is there a better command? One that effectively ignores whats in my current repository and updates it to match what is online